# How can I make better design about understanding which checkbox is checked in order to put its value to mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, html, checkbox

I have 2 checkboxes. Their values go to another php file and if any of them is checked, its value is inserted mysql codes. I did it, but when the number of checkbox increase and more advanced things appear, my code will be impossible to put into practise.

Here is checkbox.php :(it is inside a form)

```
<div>
  <label>Choose:</label>
  <label>Camera </label><input type="checkbox" name="kind[]" value="1" />
  <label>Video  </label><input type="checkbox" name="kind[]" value="2"/>
</div>
```

when the form is clicked, it goes to fetch_kind.php via AJAX and jquery($.post).
Here is code:

```
<?php

$kind = array();
$kind = $_POST['kind'];
$count = count($kind);

if ($count== 0) {
  echo "You did not checked any of checkboxes!!!";
}

if ($count == 2) {
  $sql = "SELECT id,kind FROM products";
} else {

   foreach ($kind as $value) {
     if ($value =="1") {
       $sql = "SELECT id,kind FROM products WHERE kind = " . $value;    
     }
     if ($value =="2") {
       $sql = "SELECT id,kind FROM products WHERE kind = " . $value;
     }
   }
} 

?>
```

Could you give a better example? Thank you...

Comment: Can more than one checkbox be checked? If you expect only one of them to be checked, you should use radio buttons (<input type=radio>) instead of checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to group all the values and us `IN`

```
if ($count > 0){
    $sql = "SELECT id,kind FROM products WHERE kind IN (" . implode (',', $kind) . ")"; 
}
```

Also you might want to look into sanitizing you input.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through all your checkboxes and add a simple condition to an array. You implode the array at the end.

Something like:

```
$conds = array();
foreach ($kind as $value) {
  $conds[] = '`kind` = ' . intval($value);
}

$sql = "SELECT id,kind FROM products WHERE " . implode(" OR ", $conds);
```